# a protected routes in react router v6 + vite + TS ,when i take spefice page url it's return me back to /

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

i'm trying create a protected routes in react router dom vs 6 but i have mulpie issues show one by one like when refresh page becomes blank then after fix it page return only to login any can any one help me in ,

when i refresh spefic page i tuen back to the base one why ??

i tried diffrent solutions with some new api like createBrowserRouter and but always find diffrent issues

```
import React from "react";
// import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "../pages/HomePage";
import Login from "../sign/Admin/Login";
import Signup from "../sign/Admin/Signup";
import { RootState } from "../../store";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CategoryPage from "../pages/CategoryPage";
import StorePage from "../pages/StorePage";
import ProductPage from "../pages/ProductPage";
import ServicePage from "../pages/ServicePage";
import UserPage from "../pages/UserPage";
import AdminPage from "../pages/AdminPage";
import OrderPage from "../pages/OrderPage";
import PrivateRoutes from "./PrivateRoutes";

const CustomeRoutes: React.FC = () => {
// const { isLoading, error, errorMessage } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.admin);

return (
  <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route element={<HomePage />} path="/" />
          <Route path="/categories" element={<CategoryPage />} />
          <Route path="/stores" element={<StorePage />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<ProductPage />} />
          <Route path="/services" element={<ServicePage />} />
          <Route path="/users" element={<UserPage />} />
          <Route path="/admins" element={<AdminPage />} />
          <Route path="/orders" element={<OrderPage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </>
);
};

export default CustomeRoutes;
```

App.tsx

```
import useLocalizeDocumentAttributes from "./i18n/useLocalizeDocumentAttributes";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "./store";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAdminByToken } from "./store/slices/admin";
import CutomeRoutes from "./components/routes";

function App() {
  useLocalizeDocumentAttributes();
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  // const { isLoading, error, errorMessage } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.admin);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tokenFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("user-token");
    if (tokenFromStorage) {
      dispatch(getAdminByToken(tokenFromStorage));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <CutomeRoutes />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { token, isLoading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.admin);
  console.log("PrivateRoutes=>", { token });
  React.useEffect(() => {}, [token]);
  //   if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return !!token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```

handle login

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormFields> = async (inputData, event) => {
    try {
      console.log(inputData);
      if (loginKey) {
        // If loginKey exists, dispatch acceptLoginKey action
        dispatch(acceptAdminLoginKey({ phone: inputData.phoneNumber, loginKey: parseInt(inputData.loginKey) }));
      } else {
        dispatch(loginAdmin(inputData.phoneNumber));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError("root", {
        message: "There's something wrong " + error,
      });
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
  
    if (token) {
      const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [token]);
```

Comment: i solved it after i create the private routes i add uselocaion to replace like that and it's working now `
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { token, isLoading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.admin);
  console.log("PrivateRoutes=>", { token, location });
  React.useEffect(() => {}, [token]);
  //   if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return !!token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
export default PrivateRoutes;`